# How to run NCover v1.5.8 & Gallio v3.3 on x64 machine

Tags: msbuild, mbunit, gallio, ncover

I'm struggling with NCover v1.5.8 & Gallio v3.3 on x64 machine. It can run all the tests but cannot produce the coverage report. The error message: "Profiled process terminated. Profiler connection not established"

The command line I used:

N`Cover.Console.exe Gallio.Echo.exe MyTests.dll //reg`

I tried to do the same thing as TestDriven.NET can produce the report but I have no idea where to get the "Gallio TestDriven.Net Runner". My expectation is having the coverage report from my MBUnit tests :D.

I also tried to run like this

N`Gallio.Echo.exe MyTests.dll /runner:NCover`

But it then complained about NCover 1.5.8 cannot run at .NET Fx v4.0

Anyone got the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you install Gallio (using the msi) and you already have TestDriven installed, it will install the TD.Net runner.

Comment: Thank mate. I needed it to run in console since I want to setup NCover for TeamCity. Anyway, commercial newest version solved that problem. I gave up :D